# Create a Tab layout inside fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a simple navigation drawer from Android studio build in and I upgrade that.
My question is how can I put a tab inside of one fragment?

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment  {

    View v;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
        tabimplement();
        return  v;
    }

    public void tabimplement()
    {
     // WHAT CODE WILL I PUT HERE?
    }
```

Thanks in advance. please teach me im newbie here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this to handle the Tabs:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    //Mandatory Constructor
    public MainFragment() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs,container, false);


        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Fragment B"),
                FragmentB.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Fragment C"),
                FragmentC.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator("Fragment D"),
                FragmentD.class, null);


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

With the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

The MotherActivity to host the MainFragment:

```
public class MotherActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainFragment fragmenttab = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragmenttab).commit();


    }
```

And MotherActivity layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

After this just create the normal fragment B and C, etc Class. The Result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sir by the way i got a best tutorial for this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yK8RtB6aXC4 IF there somebody need this thing